# angular, loop object array in a select and show two values

Tags: json, angularjs

I am working in app and i get this complicated situation with select and the select value.
I have a json answer "portions" if it is necessary i can re-arrange my json to solve my problem.

```
"products": [
    {...},
    {...},
    {
        // Here the json
        "id": 13,   
        "hightlighted": true,   
        // Here the portions that i loop in the "select"
        "portions": [
            {
              "size": "De 10 a 20 porciones",
              "price": "20"
            },
            {
              "size": "De 20 a 30 porciones",
              "price": "30"
            },
            {
              "size": "De 30 a 40 porciones",
              "price": "40"
            }
        ]
    }
]

<div class="item" ng-repeat="product in products">
// Here is my try one
<select class="form-control" ng-init="size=product.portions[0].size" ng-model="size" >
    <option ng-repeat="p in product.portions" value="[[p.size]]" > 
        [[p.size]]
    </option>
</select>
<div>
    [[I need here the selected PRICE]] <br>
    [[size]] <br>
</div>

// My try 2
<select class="form-control" ng-init="price=product.portions[0].price" ng-model="price" >
    <option ng-repeat="p in product.portions" value="[[p.price]]" > 
        [[p.size]]
    </option>
</select>
<div>
    [[price]] <br>
    [[I need here the selected SIZE]]
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you for any help.

edit.
I am using [[]] instead of {{}}

```
.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});
```

Here the solution !!!
thanks 
[solution](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbaJJv)

Comment: You should be using {{ }} for data binding, not [[ ]]. See the docs for select here: [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

Comment: @buzzsaw i am using [[ ]] instead of {{ }}.

Comment: Can you also add your controller and where is it in html?

Comment: Didn't realize you had modified the provider.

Comment: Your question would be easier to answer if you told use what you want to achieve. What do you want the end result to be? What do you want the select box to look like?

Comment: @JakaKonda my controller only post the array "products" the loop is working.

Comment: @JBNizet In html example i wrote what i need, i made it the more clear prosible.

Comment: If that's what you need, then use that code. Oh, it doesn't work, then it's actually not what you need. But then we can't figure out what you need, because all we have is code that doesn't work.

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry my friend, i try to made it more easy as posible and easy to understand my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better I think to use ng-options.  Ng-init should only be used for ng-repeat aliasing.

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
})

.controller('MyController', function($scope){

  $scope.product = {
"id": 13,   
"hightlighted": true,   
// Here the portions that i loop in the "select"
"portions": [
    {
      "size": "De 10 a 20 porciones",
      "price": "20"
    },
    {
      "size": "De 20 a 30 porciones",
      "price": "30"
    },
    {
      "size": "De 30 a 40 porciones",
      "price": "40"
    }
]
    }
  
  $scope.product.selectedPortion = $scope.product.portions[0];
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="MyController">
<select class="form-control" ng-options="p as p.size for p in product.portions" ng-model="product.selectedPortion" >
</select>
<div>
    [[product.selectedPortion.price]] <br>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, i made it on code pen and works, also i made a little change [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbaJJv)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

Given that I understand your case, `select as label for value in array` is the correct approach.

```
<select ng-options="portion.price as portion.size for portion in portions">
```

Comment: Good answer same as mine but more concise.

Comment: Thank you @KGChristensen It helped me too to solve my problem, here the solution [solution](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbaJJv)